# How to measure the compilation time of a document?

Tags: compiling, performance

I have a long `.tex` file and I want to know the compilation time: duration, begin - finish.

Can I add this information to the PDF or display it in `.log` file?

Comment: If you use `arara`, it will tell you the time it took. Other than that you can use, say, `l3bechmark`. Or some other tool: if you're using Linux, you can do `time pdflatex mydoc.tex`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik good suggestions, but those do not print the times to the pdf or log file as asked in the question (maybe `l3benchmark` does that or can do that, the manual only talks about 'printing to the terminal' but possibly that also means the log file?)

Comment: @Marijn `l3benchmark` prints to the terminal (and to the log, by consequence). It could be changed to print to the pdf, if needed. `arara` has its own log file, if asked for. `time` is a command line tool, so no log for that one. I posted an answer with my three suggestions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are quite a few options. Here are three:

#### From within LaTeX, using `l3benchmark`

Add this to the very top of your document:

```latex
\RequirePackage{l3benchmark}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\AtEndDocument { \benchmark_toc: }
\benchmark_tic:
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

The `\benchmark_tic:` instruction will start a timer, and `\AtEndDocument` the corresponding `\benchmark_toc:` will measure the time elapsed since the `\benchmark_tic:`. This will usually be enough to measure the execution time of your document: it will only include an extra `\ExplSyntaxOff` and exclude some of the `\end{document}` code. If you want to be *really* precise, then you can load `etoolbox` and replace that with (test document included):

```latex
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{l3benchmark}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\AfterEndDocument { \benchmark_toc: }
\use:n
  {
    \ExplSyntaxOff
    \benchmark_tic:
  }
% Test document:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-150]
\end{document}
```

The `\benchmark_tic:` will start right before your document, and the `\benchmark_toc:` will be (almost) the last thing TeX will do before exiting. However this time does not include the initialisation of the TeX engine (should be negligible), and the final processing for the inclusion of fonts (in pdfTeX and LuaTeX) or conversion from the DVI file to PDF (in XeTeX), which may take a little while, depending on the size of the document and the number of included font files.

Running that the terminal (and the `.log` file) will contain a `(l3benchmark) + TIC` at the beginning, and then a `(l3benchmark) + TOC: 0.745 s` before the final messages from the TeX engine.

#### Using `arara` to run the job and time it

With the same example document, using an `arara` header and running it:

```latex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-150]
\end{document}
```

the terminal will show:

```
phelype@oleinik ~/tex.sx> arara test.tex
  __ _ _ __ __ _ _ __ __ _ 
 / _` | '__/ _` | '__/ _` |
| (_| | | | (_| | | | (_| |
 \__,_|_|  \__,_|_|  \__,_|

Processing 'test.tex' (size: 60 KB, last modified: 08/26/2019
17:14:41), please wait.

(PDFLaTeX) PDFLaTeX engine .............................. SUCCESS

Total: 1.22 seconds
phelype@oleinik ~/tex.sx>
```

so you have to bear in mind that `arara` adds some overhead time, but it shouldn't be significant in larger jobs. If you run `arara` with `-l` (`--log`) it will create an `arara.log` file, whose final line will be something like:

```
26 ago 2019 17:20:20.548 INFO  - Total: 1.22 seconds
```

#### Using some other tool

If you're on Linux, you can use the command line tool `time`:

```sh
phelype@oleinik ~/tex.sx> time pdflatex test.tex
```

after the processing the terminal will look like this:

```
Transcript written on test.log.

real    0m1.009s
user    0m0.984s
sys     0m0.024s
```

indicating approximately 1 s of run time.

Other systems might have other tools to do the same task, e.g. `measure-command` in Windows Powershell.

---

#### Conclusion?

The same document consistently reported in my system (approximate times, but not much difference between one run and the next):

```
(l3benchmark) + TOC: 0.745 s
Total: 1.22 seconds
real    0m1.009s
```

which probably means that TeX took 0.745 s to process my document, another 0.264 s (1.009 – 0.745) for the inclusion of fonts and closing the PDF file, and `arara` took 0.220 s on top of that to do its thing. So depending on what *exactly* you want to measure, one way or another will give a better result, but all should be approximately equal for large enough jobs.

Note that since `l3benchmark` measures from *within* the TeX run, the time it will print correspond to one TeX run only.  If your document needs multiple runs and/or external tools like BibTeX, MakeIndex, etc. then the time that `arara` or `time` or whatever tool will print will certainly be bigger than the time printed by `l3benchmark`, because they add up the time to run *all* processes, rather than one single TeX run.

Again, depends what on what you want to measure:  if you're interested in the performance of your TeX code, then go for `l3benchmark`, but if you're interested in the time that it really takes to run the job, then use something else.

Comment: One point of caution! `time` in Bash is a builtin (see `help time`) and does _not_ offer the same formatting options (`-f`) as the command line tool(s) of the name. Either use `command time -f "..." ...` (or conversely `builtin time ...`) or it will only work for the most trivial case (like in your example).

Answer (score 2):

Building on Phelype's answer under "**Using some other tool**":

On Windows you can use `Measure-Command` in PowerShell to get results similar to `time` in Linux, e.g:

`measure-command {latexmk sample-document}`

More details at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513650/timing-a-commands-execution-in-powershell

I have a long document (~70 pages with a long bibliography and lots of fonts) that takes 1 min 43 sec for first compilation, but `l3benchmark` only records 21 sec in the `.log` file.

**Note**: `measure-command` does not work with the continuous preview function of `latexmk`.

Comment: `l3benchmark` only measures one run of the document, whereas `measure-command` (I assume) measures the time the process `latexmk sample-document` takes to end, and since `latexmk` runs LaTeX multiple times, that might explain the difference you see.  Thanks for the edit, by the way :-)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It might be good to mention that in your answer. You're welcome for the edit :).