# Enabling automatised support for Biblatex when using memoize

Tags: biblatex, macros, externalize, memoize, ltcmd

Note that this question concerns `memoize` version 1.1.2 (2024-01-21) and, perhaps, later.

`memoize` version 1.1.2 provides built-in support for automatic handling of `\cite` and `\cites` in memoized code when using Biblatex. I'm trying to use this to support a broader range of Biblatex citation macros.

So far I've got many such macros working using the built-in `cite` and `cites` styles. For example, his supports `\autocite`

```
  auto=\autocite{cite},
```

I've got a few more at partially working by defining a `cite field` style which uses a custom `outer handler`.

```
    auto/cite field/.style={run if memoizing, args=oomom, outer handler=\mmz@auto@citefield},
```

For example,

```
  auto csname={citefield}{cite field},
  auto csname={citelist}{cite field},
  auto csname={citename}{cite field},
```

with `outer handler`

```
\NewDocumentCommand \mmz@auto@citefield { O{} O{} m O{} m}
{% purloined from memoize.sty & mangled
  \xtoksapp\mmzCCMemo{%
    \noexpand\nocite{#3}%
  }%
  \AdviceOriginal[#1][#2]{#3}[#4]{#5}%  
}
```

However, the context-sensitivity doesn't work correctly so I need

```
    auto csname={abx@missing}{abort},
```

and nothing is auto-regenerated if, say, the output of the citation command changes.

What would be the best way to define `\mmz@auto@citefield`?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{memoize}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\mmzset{%
  prefix=memos/,
  begindocument/before/.append style={%
    auto=\autocite{cite},
    auto csname={abx@missing}{abort},
    auto/cite field/.style={run if memoizing, args=oomom, outer handler=\mmz@auto@citefield},
    auto csname={citefield}{cite field},
    auto csname={citelist}{cite field},
    auto csname={citename}{cite field},
  },
}
\NewDocumentCommand \mmz@auto@citefield { O{} O{} m O{} m}
{% purloined from memoize.sty & mangled
  \xtoksapp\mmzCCMemo{%
    \noexpand\nocite{#3}%
  }%
  \AdviceOriginal[#1][#2]{#3}[#4]{#5}%  
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [draw] {\autocite{westfahl:space}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [draw] {\citefield{westfahl:space}{booktitle}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [draw] {\citename{westfahl:space}{author}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [draw] {\citelist{westfahl:space}{location}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. First time I read of the memoize package. May I ask, what are you using the package for in general?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Externalising Ti*k*Z images. It is much, much nicer than the standard `externalize`: more automated, more robust, faster, more secure and the author has not abandoned it. (Not that I know of, anyway.)

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/698404/externalizing-large-tikz-figures/698555#698555 for my introduction to the first CTAN version. (There are some new upsides and downsides in the current version, but this is pretty close.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that sounds promising.